# Seperate Thread which calls a method which runsOnUiThread

Tags: android, threadpool

i got a FixedSizeThreadPool with 1 Thread(because i only Need one and every following request should wait till the earlier request has been finished):

```
myService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    myService.execute(new WorkerRunnable());
```

In my WorkerRunnable i do some stuff and in the middle i call a method from my Activity:

```
myActivity.thisMethodRunsOnUiThread();
```

The Method Looks like this:

```
public void thisMethodRunsOnUiThread() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            I'm trying to Change a View here, that's why i Need to do this on Ui Thread
        }

    });
}
```

And after that on the WorkerRunnable there Comes my last Method which should again run on the seperateThread from the fixedSizePool

```
myActivity.thisMethodsRunsonUiThread();
thisMethodRunsAgainOnTheSeperateThread();
```

But what i mentioned here is that he only calls the method which should RunOnUiThread after the MethodWhichShouldRunOnSeperateThread.(Which is the last method so my Thread would be finished at this time). Could it be that the seperateThread got a higher priority as the MainThread so that he waits till the seperateThread is finished and then he starts the method which runs on the UiThread?

I Need to finish the method

```
myActivity.thisMethodsRunsonUiThread();
```

before this method

```
thisMethodRunsAgainOnTheSeperateThread();
```

Can somebody explain why he acts like that? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

if the current thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue of the UI thread

Hence, this runnable must wait some time to be executed

You can use `wait()` and `notify()/notifyAll()` java methods for thread manipulation

Comment: Can you provide some code for better understanding? Because you said the runnable must wait some time to be executed. That's not true in this case. I also declared a static boolean variable which Switch to true if if the UIThread method is finished. And i packed the method on the seperate thread in a while Loop and asked if the boolean was set to true. But the while-Loop runs endless, the UIMethod is never called because the seperateThread is never finished. I hope you understand. Maybe i missunderstand something...

Comment: can you provide your code :) you did not mention about your static boolean flag and it is strange that the method which you posted onUIThread is not executed.

Comment: Don't get my wrong, i don't want to make my code public. Furthermore it would overload the question.. i thought the best way to descibe the Problem is the way i did it above.. I think it's not strange, there must be a Logical answere.. Yes i thought now it's the right time for that Information. Any other suggestions? Would appreciate that

Comment: the only thought i have, that during rotation you leaked your activity object (mActivity), and you try to post your runnable into  and change view that were already destroyed. but without  code i cannot be sure

Comment: You mean, if i rotate my device from Portrait to landscape or vice versa? No i don't do that.. But anyway thank you for your time and help. Hope somebody can help me ;/